# How to implement "move tab to new window" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How to implement the "move tab to new window" function in Javascript? To pop-out current tab to a new window.

[image: Edge]

[image: Chrome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  Understand that the HTML engine and CSS are not the same thing as the browser, which may extend all of that with additional features.

You're describing a feature of the Chrome browser interface, and one that does not exist in any specification I'm aware of.

Comment: Can "browser.tabs.move()" do the similar thing? Did some research, js can open in window and duplicate tab. I think somehow we can do it.

Comment: You think wrong.  Browser.tabs.move() and anything of that nature are going to be accessibly by an extension or something similar -- but will not be available on a web page.